# getting message : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP cons

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

I'm getting this message: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. i can't find what is wrong, please help me
here's my docker-compose file

```
services:
  postgresqldb:
    image: 'postgres:15.1'
    container_name: 'postgresqldb'
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
      POSTGRES_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      POSTGRES_DATABASE: news_portal
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    networks:
      - apinetwork
    volumes:
      - ./postgresql/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  app:
    container_name: 'news-portal'
    image: news-portal
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgresqldb:5432/news_portal
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: 1234
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: create-drop
    depends_on:
      - postgresqldb
    networks:
      - apinetwork

networks:
  apinetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

and the Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.6 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml /app
RUN mvn dependency:resolve
COPY . /app
RUN mvn clean
RUN mvn package -DskipTests

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

The application.propeties file

```
# Server configs
server.port=8080

server.servlet.context-path=/

spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher

# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresqldb:5432/news_portal
spring.datasource.username= postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234

# JPA
spring.jpa.database= postgresql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

#Flyway
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresqldb:5432/news_portal
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/migration
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.table=schema_version
spring.flyway.schemas=public
spring.flyway.user=postgres
spring.flyway.password=1234
spring.flyway.sql-migration-prefix=V
spring.flyway.validate-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.encoding=UTF-8
```

the whole project on github
https://github.com/aidatynybekkyzy/news_portal.git

Comment: Please read [ask]. Everything should be English, directly here, with a [mre]. Personal help is not what StackOverflow offers. Please take the [tour], it would have helped you with most of those problems.

Comment: No joke, instead of `localhost:5432` try `0.0.0.0:5432`. Also `jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/news-portal` should probably be `jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0:5432/news-portal` -- not sure why you put `postgres` for host.

Comment: I did it following the tutorials on youtube, 'postgres' is the name of the container. and according to the tutorial in application.properties i should change it into the name of db container, as i understood)

Comment: The error suggest that your application is using `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/news_portal` instead of `jdbc:postgresql://postgresqldb:5432/news_portal`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Communication between docker-compose defined machines needs to use the hostnames/containernames defined in the docker-compose file.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for answer, but even when i changed localhost to postgresqldb i'm getting same error

Comment: @Aida I have a very similar setup. I used the ```host.docker.internal``` instead of localhost or container name like jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/news_portal and this works fine for me. Could you try the same?